# Why does the modulo affect other terms in the equation?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, modular-arithmetic, diophantine-equations, perfect-powers

i just want to ask if why does the modulo affect the other terms in an eqution?
Why does the 4th equation has to be multiplied by $a^2$?
Then as the modulo becomes $n≡1(mod3)$  in the 5th eq. then the power of 10 in the second term becomes 5?Ive been thinking for reasons why it happens but i cant find any, please help. Im currently studyng the journal about [POWERS](https://cs.uwaterloo.ca/journals/JIS/VOL8/Kihel/kihel7.pdf)

\begin{equation}
\label{eq:(3)} {\overline{aa \ldots ab \ldots b}}_{(10)} = y^2,
\end{equation} $$
10^{m} \cdot a \frac{10^{n} - 1}{9} = y^2 ,
$$
 $\bullet$ If $m = 3$, then equation 1 yields
$$
10^3 aa \ldots a + 111b = y^2.
$$
Hence,
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:(4)} 10^{n+3} a - 10^3 a + 999b = (3y)^2.
\end{equation}
If $n\equiv 0\pmod 3$; i.e., if $n = 3N$ for a some integer $N$,
then equation 1 yields
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:(5)} Y^2 = X^3 - 10^3 a^3 + 999 a^2 b,
\end{equation}
where $Y = 3ay$ and $X = 10^{N+1}a.$

If $n \equiv 1\pmod 3$; i.e., if $n = 3N + 1$ for some integer
$N$, then equation 1 yields
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:(6)} Y^2 = X^3 - 10^5 a^3 + 99900 a^2 b,
\end{equation}
where $Y = 30ay$ and $X = 10^{N+2}a.$
If $n \equiv 2\pmod 3$; i.e., if $n = 3N + 2$ for some integer
$N$, then equation 1 yields
\begin{equation}
\label{eq:(7)} Y^2 = X^3 - 10^7 a^3 + 9990000 a^2 b,
\end{equation}
where $Y = 300ay$ and $X = 10^{N+3}a.$

Comment: I have no idea what you are trying to ask. This question is a mess of equations left an right, with no beginning and end. Please, rephrase your question: explain what you are doing, and what equation you are stuck on. And don't say "read the link", because the link is 7 pages long, and most of it is probably not relevant to your question.

Comment: Yeah, still not making much sense. And please don't call me sir.

Comment: im stuck on this equation, If $n \equiv 1\pmod 3$; i.e., if $n = 3N + 1$ for some integer
$N$, then equation  yields
 $Y^2 = X^3 - 10^5 a^3 + 99900 a^2 b$,

where $Y = 30ay$ and $X = 10^{N+2}a.$
 i dont know why raising X to the power of a modulo affects also the other terms which makes $10^3$ becomes $10^5$

Comment: that diophantine equation comes from the form ${\overline{aa \ldots ab \ldots b}}_{(10)} = y^2$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You start with $$10^{n+3}a-10^3a+999b=(3y)^2$$ You let $n=3N+1$ to get $$10^{3N+4}a-10^3a+999b=(3y)^2$$ You multiply by 100a^2 to get $$10^{3N+6}a^3-10^5a^3+99900a^2b=(30ay)^2$$ Then you let $Y=30ay$, and $X=10^{N+2}a$ to get $$X^3-10^5a^3+99900a^2b=Y^2$$

Comment: thank you gerry i understand now how the equation is patterned,

Comment: may i know if how to solve for the integral points of those equation?or can you give me some sites,topics or any  or resources to study so as for me to solve the solution of those eqution? The only solution that the journal found which corresponds to an integer solution to equation (1) is x = 1444 and i dont know where did it get that,     what topic should i study first to know such?

Comment: In the part you've written out, the equation has been reduced to three Mordell equations. A Mordell equation is an equation of the form $y^2=x^3-k$. It's a special case of an elliptic curve, and has been studied intensively. Some of the work is elementary, but some is very deep, and there are problems still unsolved. Search the web for "Mordell equation" to get some idea of what's out there.